# How to trigger the events fom android code and handle them in html page?

Tags: android, html, youtube

I want to embed YouTube player in android. And I want to control this player of my own by triggering some events from android code. Which is the best way to do this. And how do I handle the events.

Comment: you can trigger events from javascript or redirections using webview's clients.

Answer (score 0):

Naive , 
  You can handle the HTML event using java script ..
  in android it call websppas . 
  u can learn more about it form [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html)

and you can find the example how this work form [HERE](http://connorhd.co.uk/2010/02/03/webapp-an-android-experiment/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if we want to add different events in the same HTML file, then how do I achieve this.  For Eg: i want to open one html page and pass one query string to it. If this query string is say "one" then i want to go to youtube and play video. While of the query string is "two" then i want to display the contents of html page. Please give me some sample code if you can. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @native: look i have edited my answer ..you can find small demo form there , and your requirement can be done using java script .

Comment: Thanks. That's quite helpful. Can you please guide me on one more thing. I want to have a youtube player. So, at start i want to load some video by providing the vid(video_id). Now while the video is being played, i want to change its quality on the fly. For changing the quality, i want to send the notification from android code. Please tell me how can i do this without loading the video from start.